# jaydebeapi cannot find jar on AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-s3, jdbc, aws-glue, ojdbc, jaydebeapi

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle database via jaydebeapi in Python on AWS Glue. I'm getting the error that says:

`TypeError: Class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver is not found`

I believe the error is resulted from jaydebeapi not able to find the ojdbc jar, as the same code worked locally with the path being a local path.

What should I do on AWS Glue for jaydebeapi to recognize the passed s3 path to the jar? I've tried both passing the path to `Dependent JARs path` field, and specifying `--extra-jars` in the Job parameters field.

Here is my code:

```
import jaydebeapi
props = {
   "user": "user",
   "password": "password",
   "oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion": "false"
}
conn = jaydebeapi.connect("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver",
  "jdbc:oracle:thin:/oracle@host:port/orcl", 
  props, 
  "s3://path/to/ojdbc8-21.4.0.0.1.jar", 
  libs=None)
with conn.cursor() as curs:
  curs.execute("CREATE SEQUENCE SCHEMA.TABLE")
```

Thank you in advance for sharing your insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out jaydebeapi library can't recognize S3 path as it's not local to the environment. I had to download the jar from S3 to the `/tmp/` directory of AWS Glue first as follow:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.Bucket('bucket_name').download_file('external-lib/jar/ojdbc8-21.4.0.0.1.jar','ojdbc8-21.4.0.0.1.jar')
```

Then I can load the jar in the `/tmp/`:

```
import jaydebeapi
props = {
   "user": "user",
   "password": "password",
   "oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion": "false"
}
conn = jaydebeapi.connect("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver",
  "jdbc:oracle:thin:/oracle@host:port/orcl", 
  props, 
  "/tmp/ojdbc8-21.4.0.0.1.jar", 
  libs=None)
with conn.cursor() as curs:
  curs.execute("CREATE SEQUENCE SCHEMA.TABLE")
```